# How to do spf record entry in dns?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf

I have a postfix configured cent0s 5.5 mail server in 64 bit configuration.

I want to know, how to record sender policy framework(SPF) entry in my domain name server zone files.

Answer (score 4):

The SPF record is not set by the mail server.  It is an entry in DNS, so you will need control over the DNS records for your domain.

Specifically, the SPF is a TXT record for the domain in DNS.  Your DNS management tools should have some mechanism of adding the right TXT record.

In BIND, you will have a line like this:

```
example.com IN TXT "v=spf mx ptr ~all"
```

or whatever your SPF specification happens to be.

Other management tools will be different, i.e., a web-based tool may have some sort of pull down for the record type (e.g, A, MX, TXT, CNAME, etc.).  You will need to specify how you're DNS is set up for a more specific answer.

Comment: ok i will try this and update you.

Comment: can you please tell me in which bind file i have to do this entry,i have two files in /var/named,localhost.zone and localdomain.zone.

Comment: From the names, neither.  There should be a separate zone file for your actual domain rather than localdomain/localhost.  Unless you already stuck the domain info into one of those files.  Talk to your DNS admin.